# keep cmd open while running a file

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm learning C++ and I'm using Visual C++ Express and while running this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

the cmd window closes so fast, I can't see Hello World
is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you press Control + F5, you won't be attached with a debugger - however, it'll stay open with a "Press any key to continue" style message.

Answer (score 2):

Put a getc() right before the return. The program will close only if you press any key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the common solution is to add a statement that reads input from the keyboard. This call blocks execution till some key is pressed. You can do it with statements like

```
printf("Hit \"Enter\" to continue\n");  
fflush(stdin); /* Remove anything that is currently in the standard input */  
getchar();     /* Wait for the user to hit the enter key */
```

Answer (score 1):

you can type this at the end of the main:

```
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just put a breakpoint on the return statement. No code change. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple :
write this to stop it

```
getch();
i.e

main()

{

//////
Your program

/////////

getch();

}
```